# How to show the additon of two numbers

Tags: assembly, data-conversion, emu8086

I'm giving the two inputs and want to add the numbers and show the output. but here it gives the ascii number as output. How can I solve this?

```
org 100h

mov ah,1
int 21h
mov bl,al

int 21h
mov ch,al

add bl,ch

mov ah,2
int 21h
mov dl,10
int 21h
mov dl,13
int 21h

mov ah,2
int 21h  
mov dl,bl
int 21h 

ret
```

I expect 10 when I input 5 and 5 but gettin 'j' as output

Answer (score 1):

> I expect 10 when I input 5 and 5 but gettin 'j' as output

When you input those two 5's you actually receive **characters** and **not the numbers 5**! You need to make the conversion. Simply subtracting 48 does that job.

```
  org 100h
  mov ah, 01h
  int 21h
  sub al, 48   ;Conversion
  mov bl, al
  mov ah, 01h
  int 21h
  sub al, 48   ;Conversion
```

Once you made the addition of the two numbers you'll have to convert that sum back to 1 or 2 characters depending on the value of the sum being greater than 9 or not.

```
  add bl, al
  cmp bl, 10
  jb  LessThan10
  mov dl, "1"
  mov ah, 02h
  int 21h
  sub bl, 10
LessThan10:
  add bl, 48   ;Conversion
  mov dl, bl
  mov ah, 02h
  int 21h
```

If you're going to output a carriage return and linefeed between these operations then make sure that you don't accidently destroy the contents of registers that are required in a later step. So choose the registers wisely and/or preserve them via the stack.

> ```
> mov ah,2 int 21h mov dl,10 int 21h mov dl,13 int 21h
> mov ah,2 int 21h
> ```

Please note that your code has a lot of redundant `int 21h` instructions! **More is certainly not better**.